# Facebook app results vary locally and on Heroku

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku, facebook-php-sdk

In my facebook app, there are two files index.php and write.php which uses this basic code:

```
require_once('AppInfo.php');
if (substr(AppInfo::getUrl(), 0, 8) != 'https://' && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !=    '127.0.0.1') {
    header('Location: https://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
}
require_once('utils.php');
require_once('sdk/src/facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => AppInfo::appID(),
    'secret' => AppInfo::appSecret(),
));
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
```

After the index.php is loaded, an ajax request is sent to write.php, which sends queries to Facebook and writes the results onto a text file. write.php uses the same code to initialize the Facebook object.

This works fine when tested locally, but after uploading to Heroku it gives arbitrary results. Either the $user_id is null and the code is unable to go beyond if($user_id) or the $user_id has a value of 0, which raises exceptions later.

Comment: Are both environments 64 bit?

Comment: My local machine is 32 bit. How does it make a difference?

Comment: My original question had to do with length of integers in 32 vs 64 bit environments. Facebook API might treat numbers as a string and avoid that restriction. However, it appears that a result of 0 means that the user is not logged in. Are users authenticated before hitting this code?

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook SDK stores the login data in the session. Since your AJAX request to your `write.php` does not send the complete facebook POST data, the facebook class assumes, that there is no signed request and therefore no data.

I encountered the same behaviour some times and the problem was always, that the session was not established correctly. Unfortunately I am not quite sure, what the exact cause was.